# How to replace object key with matching key value from another object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object:

`{pm: 'val 1', dm: 'val 2', cm: 'val 3'}`

and I want to loop through this and check if any of the keys are present in another object,

if they are then replace the key with the matching keys value from the other object.

`{pm: 'price', dm: 'discount', cm: 'cost'}`

The expected output would be:

`{price: 'val 1', discount: 'val 2', cost: 'val 3'`

Comment: In case they are not present in another object do you want the key/value in final object ?

Comment: Yeah I just realised now this is a perfect scenario where everything matches but I need it to work if say only `pm` is present in the first object.

Comment: You want the remaining key/value unchanged  included in final output ?

Comment: The second object is going to be created manually so it will definitely have all possible matching keys. I was worried about me not passing the exact same keys in the first object but after testing one of the answers it seems to work in that scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `reduce`, check the existence of key in another object and than add the value from `anotherObj` as key in final object

```js
let obj = {pm: 'val 1', dm: 'val 2', cm: 'val 3', 'xy':'val 4'}
let anotherObj = {pm: 'price', dm: 'discount', cm: 'cost'}

let final = Object.entries(obj).reduce((op, [key,value]) => {
  let newKey = anotherObj[key]
  op[newKey || key ] = value
  return op
},{})

console.log(final)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the most efficient way of doing it.
Check performance of all above answers [here](http://jsben.ch/2tnyP).

```js
var obj1 = {pm: 'val 1', dm: 'val 2', cm: 'val 3', mm: 'val 4'};
var obj2 = {pm: 'price', dm: 'discount', cm: 'cost'};
var output = {};

for(var key in obj1){
  if(obj2[key]){
    output[obj2[key]] = obj1[key];
  } else {
    output[key] = obj1[key];
  }
};

console.log(output)
```

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Answer (score 1):

Use `reduce` with `Object.entries`:

```js
const obj1 = {pm: 'val 1', dm: 'val 2', cm: 'val 3'};
const obj2 = {pm: 'price', dm: 'discount', cm: 'cost'};
const res = Object.entries(obj1).reduce((acc, [k, v]) => ({ ...acc, [obj2[k] || k]: v }), {});
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in following steps:

- Get the entries of first object using `Object.entries()`
- Use `map()` on the array of entries.
- In map check if the current key is present on second object then return a entry with changed key otherwise the same one.
- At last use `Object.fromEntries()` to get an object.

```js
const obj1 = {pm: 'val 1', dm: 'val 2', cm: 'val 3'}
const obj2 = {pm: 'price', dm: 'discount', cm: 'cost'}

const res = Object.fromEntries(
                Object.entries(obj1)
                     .map(([k,v]) => [(obj2[k] || k), v])
            )

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the key object into an array using `Object.entries` and loop thru the array using `reduce`

```js
var val = {"pm":"val 1","dm":"val 2","cm":"val 3"};
var key = {"pm":"price","dm":"discount","cm":"cost"};

var result = Object.entries(key).reduce((c, [v, k]) => Object.assign(c, {[k]: val[v] || null}), {});

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) in a concise way like this:

```js
let vals = {pm: 'val 1', dm: 'val 2', cm: 'val 3'}
let keys = {pm: 'price', dm: 'discount', cm: 'cost'}

let result = Object.keys(keys).reduce((r,k) => (r[keys[k]] = vals[k]) && r, {})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access, and define the keys with obj[key] syntax. See below how the code loops through `obj2`, and if it matches it makes the new node on res with the value from `obj2[key]` as the key (`res[obj2[key]]`). I added an additional key `mm` so you can see what happens when it doesn't match.

```js
const obj1 = {pm: 'val 1', dm: 'val 2', cm: 'val 3', mm: 'val 4'};
const obj2 = {pm: 'price', dm: 'discount', cm: 'cost'};
const res = {};

for(let key in obj1){
  if(obj2[key]){
    res[obj2[key]] = obj1[key];
  } else {
    res[key] = obj1[key];
  }
};

console.log(res);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code

```
const obj1 = {pm: 'val 1', dm: 'val 2', cm: 'val 3'},
  obj2 = {pm: 'price', dm: 'discount', cm: 'cost'},
  obj = {};
Object.keys(obj2).forEach( key2 => {
   Object.keys(obj1).forEach( key1 => {
      if (key2 === key1) {
        obj[obj2[key2]] = obj1[key1]
      }
   });
 });
console.log(obj)
```

This is a demo https://codepen.io/phuongnm153/pen/PvmeEN

Answer (score 0):

A very straight forward way:

```
let obj = {pm: 'val 1', dm: 'val 2', cm: 'val 3'};
let otherObj = { dm: 'val 9'}

for(let key in obj){
  if(otherObj[key] != null) {
     obj[key] = otherObj[key]
  }
}
```