# Javascript: How to replace first object's values with values from second object, if objects have matching keys

Tags: javascript

I have 2 js objects:

```
var date_dict = {2017_M1: 0, 2017_M10: 0, 2017_M11: 0}
var data_dict = {2017_M1: 10,  2017_M11: 50}
```

Expected output =  `{2017_M1: 10, 2017_M10: 0, 2017_M11: 50}`

Aim: To map the values of data_dict (target) to date_dict (source) where they exist.
Keep all keys of date_dict (source). Keep values of date_dict if not exist in data_dict.

There will never be any keys in data_dict that do not exist in date_dict (this is universe of dates).

I've tried, based on switching key/value an answer to
[How to replace object key with matching key value from another object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56178953/how-to-replace-object-key-with-matching-key-value-from-another-object)

Below attempt just returns the date_dict, it doesn't get the data_dict values.

Thanks
:

```
var expected_output = Object.fromEntries(
                Object.entries(date_dict).map(([k,v]) => [ k, (data_dict[v] || v)])
```

Comment: do you want to keep the same object?

Comment: Console.log({ ...obj1, ...obj2 }) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the spread operator for this:

```
const expected_output = {
  ...date_dict,
  ...data_dict
};
```